# How to enable live-view on Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I am extremely new to using Xcode and am just beginning to learn Swift, in all the tutorials I've been watching they all are able to look at a live-view of the work they're doing. I was just wondering if anyone could help me enable that live-view and suggest a beginner's guide for me to watch?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Tools/libs/docs recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: You're referring to a Playground most probably.

Comment: I've tried a few lines of code that were suggested on forums:

Comment: PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

Comment: I've also tried                                                                                  import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = .white
view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

Comment: Live view works only for Playgrounds, if you are trying to enable it in Xcode project it won't work.